# What is the proper way to shut down a successful OpenSSL connection?

Tags: c, openssl, shutdown

In C code (running in Ubuntu 20 Linux) I have sent a test email to a gmail address. The email is sent and arrives ok at the recipient.
Now I want to shut down the connection properly. My shutdown code is as follows:

```
...
if (ctx!=NULL)
   SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
printf("SSL closed!\n");
if (ssl!=NULL)
   {
   i=0;
   while (i<5)
      {
      iResult = SSL_shutdown(ssl);
      if (iResult == 0)
         {
         printf("SSL shutdown in progress...\n");
         iResult=SSL_get_error(ssl,iResult);
         printf("iResult: %d\n",iResult);
         switch (iResult)
            {
            case SSL_ERROR_NONE:  //0
                 break;
            case SSL_ERROR_SSL:   //1
                 break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:   //2
                 iResult = SSL_read(ssl, recvbuf, BUFLEN - 1);
                 if (iResult>0)
                    printf("Byte(s) received: %d\n", iResult);
                 break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:   //3
                 break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_X509_LOOKUP:  //4
                 break;
            case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:   //5
                 break;
            case SSL_ERROR_ZERO_RETURN:  //6
                 break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CONNECT:  //7
                 break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ACCEPT:  //8
                 break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC:  //9
                 break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_ASYNC_JOB:  //10
                 break;
            case SSL_ERROR_WANT_CLIENT_HELLO_CB:  //11
                 break;
            default:
                 break;
            }
         }
      else if (iResult == 1)
         {
         printf("SSL shutdown succeeded\n");
         break;
         }
      else if (iResult == -1)
         {
         printf("SSL shutdown failed! %d\n",SSL_get_error(ssl,iResult));
         sleep(1);
         iResult = SSL_shutdown(ssl);
         break;
         }
      sleep(1);
      i++;
      }
   SSL_free(ssl);
   }

//
if (sock>0)
   {
   iResult = shutdown(sock, SHUT_RDWR);
   if (iResult == -1)
      {
      printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", errno);
      }
   else
      printf("shutdown succeeded\n");
   iResult = close(sock);
   if (iResult < 0)
      {
      printf("Error occurred while closing socket\n");
      }
   }
```

I am getting the following output:

```
221 2.0.0.0 closing connection..
SSL closed!
SSL shutdown in progress...
iResult: 5
SSL shutdown failed! 5
shutdown failed: 107
```

Error 5 is SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL

I've tried a number of ways but never seem to get past the error at shutdown.
What is the proper way to shut down a successful session?

Comment: The output does not match with the provided code. 
For some reason the 1st "iResult: %d" is before the 1st "SSL shutdown in progress..."

Comment: You are right. I copied the output from terminal by hand since my terminal had no copy/paste. I edited my question with corrected output.

Comment: According to man page of SSL_get_error: ret==0 and SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL indicates EOF (peer closed TCP connection).  Maybe peer closed the TCP connection too early?
Are you using non-blocking BIO? It looks like that non-blocking BIO is used wrongly.

Comment: I am not using non-blocking BIO. Could it be that Gmail/google has closed the connection at the receiving end? socket is opened with sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); and  ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method()); and ssl = SSL_new(ctx); and SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock); SSL_connect(ssl);
Then I just SSL_write and SSL_read and finally start the shutdown